# Error in MPEG-DASH with Azure Media Services

Tags: android, azure, exoplayer, azure-media-services

I am trying to implement Video on Demand using Azure Media Services on Android.

I have uploaded the video, encoded it to Multi-Bitrate MP4 and then added AES encryption and published it.

I received this MPEG-DASH Url: http://prepladder-inct.streaming.media.azure.net/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx/sample-video.ism/manifest(format=mpd-time-csf)

But i am unable to play this video on any MPEG-DASH player (Android or web)

I am even unable to play this video on Azure dash player link: http://dashplayer.azurewebsites.net/

When i enter the stream url, the player is able to show the duration of the video but does not play.

[image]

On ExoPlayer on Android, i am able to play all MPEG-DASH streams available online for testing purpose.

Also, i am able to play HLS stream provided by Azure for the same media on ExoPlayer and on iOS.

I have not added any token authorization or DRM during video encryption.

I am missing something? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that your video file name has unsupported characters. The issue is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-dotnet-upload-files), where we point out that certain characters should not be used. Try renaming the source video to, say, GM_1st_acid_fast_stain.mp4, upload it to a new Asset, encode, and then create the streaming URL.

Comment: Hi Anil. Thank you for sharing this info. I have uploaded a new asset but the problem still exists. Here is another link i created from a new asset: http://prepladder-inct.streaming.media.azure.net/354aa663-a0cb-4801-a327-c90828775f54/dec.ism/manifest(format=mpd-time-csf)

Comment: Hi. I am able to play the videos by removing AES encryption. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad to know - let us know if you need information on setting up playback of encrypted content.

Comment: Hi Anil. I have now encrypted my videos using PlayReady and Widevine with MPEG-DASH + FairPlay with HLS. When i try to play Fairplay video, i gave the skd value to the player but video is not playing. I read online that i need to pass some SPC value and get CKC value. But i don't know how to do that. Is there any simpler documentation available on how to implement this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For FairPlay/HLS, it is critical to provide the Application Cert (public key only) to the player. Apple's recommended way is to host this App Cert on a web server and pass the URL to player.

SPC/CKC negotiation is performed inside the player.

I would suggest to use this test/diag tool http://aka.ms/amtest which is equipped to support all 3 DRMs (FairPlay, Widevine, PlayReady) and AES-128. If you expand "player_settings" you will see an entry called "FPS AC Path" which is where you paste in your App Cert URL. Also put in "FairPlay" under protectionInfo.type. Of course you need to run the test in Safari on macOS.

Hope this helps.
William

Comment: Hi William, Thanks for the info. The demo FairPlay streaming app provided by Apple asks for licence path in skd format. Azure portal shows a url with this format: skd://xxx.keydelivery.centralindia.media.azure.net/FairPlay/ but this does not play the video. The demo app asks for only 2 things. One is the manifest file and other is licence url. Can you please help me how to get this licence url.

Comment: linked site is no longer available.